# Is there a way to run a tool script without attaching it to a node in the scene tree?

Tags: godot, editors, gdscript

What I want to do is run a tool script on the editor.
The usual way would be to attach it to a scene tree node, but then I'd have to guard it with `if`s all over to prevent editor code to be run at runtime and viceversa.

I could instantiate the script and run it directly without it being attached to a node, but the script that instantiates that script would have to be tool too, so not getting rid of the problem.

I guess I could create a node in the scene tree with a tool script attached, that removes itself from the scene tree once the game is running.

Is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Like some kind of project setting to run a tool script on project load?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this answer I present a few approaches to run code in the editor. The first one is pretty much what you are already doing. If that is an option for you, it is an option for you.

The second is using `EditorScript`. Which technically accomplishes the "without attaching it to a node in the scene tree" requirement. But it is limited in what it can do.

The third is using `EditorPlugin`. Which solves the "run a tool script on project load" requirement. Except, oh, surprise, the Godot IDE has a scene tree, *which is not the scene tree of the game*. I believe that `EditorPlugin` is what you want.

Well, I suppose there is another way: Writing a [Godot Module](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/cpp/custom_modules_in_cpp.html) (with C++), which require building Godot from source to include. See [Compiling](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/index.html).

---

### `tool` script

As you are aware, you can run GDScript in the IDE by making script a `tool` script (using the `tool` keyword). And you can check [`Engine.editor_hint`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_engine.html#class-engine-property-editor-hint) to know when the code is running in the IDE.

Following that idea, you can have `tool` script, where check `Engine.editor_hint` is `true` and then instance there whatever you want to run only on the editor. If what you instanced there, is only instanced there… Well, you can forgo further checking.

*And yes, I suppose you can have it remove itself.*

---

### EditorScript

Create a new script that inherits from [`EditorScript`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_editorscript.html). Make sure it is a `tool` script. Give it a `_run` function:

```
tool
extends EditorScript

func _run():
    print("Hello from the Godot Editor!")
```

This script runs from the Script Editor. With the script open, go to the File menu, and select Run. You can also use secondary click on the script on the Scripts Panel (on the left of the Script Editor) and select Run in the contextual menu.

---

### EditorPlugin

Go to the Project menu, then Project Settings, on the Plugin tab, click create.

It will open a dialog asking about the details of your plugin. At minimum give it a Name (first field), a subfolder (second field) and a Script Name (last field). You can leave the rest blank (and even edit it later).

It will generate a script that looks like this:

```
tool
extends EditorPlugin

func _enter_tree() -> void:
    pass

func _exit_tree() -> void:
    pass
```

This script runs on the editor only. You can enable it and disable it on the Plugin tab of the Project Settings (where you create it). And yes, this is how you make plugins/addons for Godot.

When you enable it (or when you load a project where it is enabled) it will run `_enter_tree`. Similarly when disabling (or unloading a project where it is enabled) it will run `_exit_tree`.

*To be clear, these will not run when you run the game (because, again, this script runs on the editor only).*

Reminder: The Godot UI is made with Godot. It has a scene tree.

The [`EditorPlugin`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_editorplugin.html) API will give you access to more parts of the IDE that you usually would.

Refer to [Editor plugins](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/plugins/editor/index.html) and `plugin` folder of the official godot-demo-projects repository ([on Github](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-demo-projects/tree/master/plugins/addons)).